# Creating loops for x and y attribute when appending to create a grid of squares in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, d3.js

I'm making a grid of squares, where each square is linked to a datapoint.

I'm trying increment the y attribute value and reset the x attribute value after every 5 squares in a row. How do you create a loop for this?

Ideally it should allow for as many data points to be added so that after every 5 squares in a row, a new row is created.

Below is the setup:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40];

var rectangle = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
        x:function(d, i){ 
          if(i<5){
           return i*60 + 5 
          }else{
             
            }   
        },
        y:function(d, i){ 
         d = 80
         if(i<5){
           return d
          }else{
            return d+40
          }},
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'red'
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%"></svg>
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlw01/9yak00f6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like the code below:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10];

var rectangle = svg
    .attr('width', window.innerWidth)
    .attr('height', window.innerHeight)
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
        x:function(d, i){ 
          return i % 5 * 60  // use modulo operator to set x coord
        },
        y:function(d, i){ 
          return Math.floor(i / 5) * 60 
        },  
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'red'
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%"></svg>
```